# Form is not showing the btn bootstrap class in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I imported "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0" and my form is working fine but I have this issue with the btn bootstrap class, it is not showing at all, but labels, text and textarea are.

```
{!! 
... 

{{ Form::submit('Create Post', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block')) }} 

... 
!!}
```

I am using `Laravel 5.4`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I had `null` as an argument. Working now!